# Removing a GFI outlet in laundry room

Tags: electrical

I had an electrician come and add an outlet so that the washer could have a dedicated outlet. They added a second outlet (GFI) that trips both outlets when I run the heavy duty washer on a big load. The washer is a Maytag and is brand new-had them out to check it-and the repair man said this is common with this model. Can I simply pull out the new gfi and install a standard outlet? Washing machine is currently running on an extension cord without interruption . Thoughts?

Comment: What State are you located in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For older homes, if your washer's in a garage or unfinished basement you have to have GFCI protection. If it's in a utility room and the outlet is ***not*** within 6 feet of a sink it doesn't need the GFCI. If you make changes, such as adding an outlet, then the laundry room needs GFCI protection as Kris pointed out from the 2017 code.

Comment: + 1 for adding the clarification.

Comment: @Kris  Been retired for a while,,, amazing how fast things change...  Thanks

Answer (score 4):

NEC 2017, which is the most adopted version currently, requires at least one dedicated 20A circuit to at least one or all receptacles in the laundry room and all require GFCI protection -- 210.8(A)(10) and they should be accessible where they can be tested and reset as per the manufacturer instructions.  This means not stuffed behind the washer at the bottom where you can't reach it without having to remove the washer.

Also worth noting is the laundry room lights are NOT allowed to be on the laundry circuit.  I know a lot of people have their washer and dryer in the most odd places so this is a often overlooked code for older homes.

For your current situation I'd recommend getting a different model washing machine as safety from GFCI protection can be the difference of life and death.

Comment: Iirc they also require dedicated circuits?

Comment: That's correct.  At least one dedicated 20A circuit for the receptacles. The lights are not allowed to be on it, nor are you required to have a 220v for the dryer. I updated my answer. Thanks for pointing that out